# scrollIntoView using Vue 3 script setup

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, js-scrollintoview

Im trying to scroll to a specific element onclick. But I get the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: element.scrollIntoView is not a function
```

This is my script

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

function goTo(refName){
    let element = ref(refName);
   element.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"})
}

</script>
```

This is my click function

```
<DayWithText v-for="day in daysOfWeek" :name="day.shortHand" :day="day.day" :date="day.date"  @click.prevent="goTo('test')"/>
```

This is the element

```
<p ref="test">test</p>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I could make it work, working with ID instead of refs

Comment: It's a mistake to call `ref` inside goTo, it physically can't work this way and should stay at top level. Check Check https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#refs-inside-v-for  . It's unclear how these snippets are related, please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 4):

`ref('test')` does not return `<p ref="test">test</p>`. It creates a new `ref` with initial value of `'test'` (string).

To get that paragraph, you have to declare it as

```js
const test = ref(null)
```

inside `<script setup>` (before `mount`).

At any time after the component mounted

```
test.value?.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"})
```

will work.

Demo:

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;

createApp({
  setup() {
    const test = ref(null);
    const goToTest = () => {
      test.value?.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "center"})
    }
    return {
      test,
      goToTest
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```css
#app p {
  margin: 200vh 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="goToTest">Go to test</button>
  <p ref="test">test</p>
</div>
```

---

Under the hood, on `mount`, when the `<template>` parser finds a `ref`, it looks into `setup` scope for the declared variable with that name. If found and if it's a `ref`, the current DOM element is placed in that ref's `value`.

Answer (score 3):

In my case

```
const refName = ref(null);

const goTo = () => {
    refName.value.$el.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
}
```

html

```
<div @click="goTo()">scroll to</div>
<p id="refName">Scrolled position</p>
```

worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I solved it as follows.

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
const scrollToElem = ()=> {
    document.getElementById("pagetop")?.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
}
</script>
<template>
<div>
   <div id="pagetop" class="content">
      Bla bla bla...
   </div>
</div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

For typescript it is:

```
    const test= ref<null | HTMLDivElement>(null);

    test.value?.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"})
```